# Oracle - SQL adding a row once a group of values completed

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE TABLE "OPERATE" ("SQL_ID" VARCHAR2(13 BYTE), "CHILD_NUMBER" NUMBER, "COMMAND_TYPE" NUMBER );
Insert into OPERATE (SQL_ID,CHILD_NUMBER,COMMAND_TYPE) values ('6z0vqndtyx6w4',211,2);
Insert into OPERATE (SQL_ID,CHILD_NUMBER,COMMAND_TYPE) values ('74jdcz9vdg9dw',0,2);
Insert into OPERATE (SQL_ID,CHILD_NUMBER,COMMAND_TYPE) values ('097nk49ptumbm',1,2);
Insert into OPERATE (SQL_ID,CHILD_NUMBER,COMMAND_TYPE) values ('00jchz9tqxqwg',1,3);
Insert into OPERATE (SQL_ID,CHILD_NUMBER,COMMAND_TYPE) values ('00qxnvf7p1sxg',0,3);
Insert into OPERATE (SQL_ID,CHILD_NUMBER,COMMAND_TYPE) values ('1awzurfqvtf32',0,6);
Insert into OPERATE (SQL_ID,CHILD_NUMBER,COMMAND_TYPE) values ('3zzqvtya411wb',0,6); commit;

select * from operate;

output:
COMMAND_TYPE, SQL_ID, CHILD_NUMBER
2   6z0vqndtyx6w4   211
2   74jdcz9vdg9dw   0
2   097nk49ptumbm   1
3   00jchz9tqxqwg   1
3   00qxnvf7p1sxg   0
6   1awzurfqvtf32   0
6   3zzqvtya411wb   0

Expecting:
COMMAND_TYPE, SQL_ID, CHILD_NUMBER
2   6z0vqndtyx6w4   211
2   74jdcz9vdg9dw   0
2   097nk49ptumbm   1
2   2               2 **-- want to print value of command_type (in each column or one column, there are total 3 columns) once all the rows of a command_type have come (as shown in o/p), command_type values are dynamic, pls suggest.**
3   00jchz9tqxqwg   1
3   00qxnvf7p1sxg   0
3   3               3 **--** 
6   1awzurfqvtf32   0
6   3zzqvtya411wb   0
6   6               6 **--**
```

Please suggest. I have asked the question in the above output. 
Have to write this again to post it "want to print value of command_type (in each column or one column, there are total 3 columns) once all the rows of a command_type have come (as shown in o/p), command_type values are dynamic"

Answer (score 3):

You can apply GROUPING SETS:

```
select
   COMMAND_TYPE, SQL_ID,CHILD_NUMBER
from operate
group by grouping sets
  ((COMMAND_TYPE, SQL_ID, CHILD_NUMBER),
   (COMMAND_TYPE));
order by 1
```

This will return NULL for SQL_ID and CHILD_NUMBER, if you actually need to repeat the COMMAND_TYPE you must apply `COALESCE`.

Btw, displaying data is usually handled in the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query :

```
select COMMAND_TYPE,
nvl(SQL_ID,COMMAND_TYPE) sql_id,
nvl(CHILD_NUMBER,command_type)CHILD_NUMBER
FROM (
select COMMAND_TYPE, SQL_ID,CHILD_NUMBER
from operate
union all
select distinct command_Type, null ,null
from operate)
order by command_type, child_number nulls last;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use analytics function like that:

```
select t1.a command_type,
       t1.b sql_id,
       t1.c child_number
       from (
            select COMMAND_TYPE a, nvl(SQL_ID,command_type) b, nvl(CHILD_NUMBER,command_type) c, grouping_id(COMMAND_TYPE, SQL_ID,CHILD_NUMBER) from test_operate
            group by cube(COMMAND_TYPE,SQL_ID,CHILD_NUMBER)
            having (child_number is not null and command_type is not null and SQL_ID is not null)
            or (child_number is  null and command_type is  not null and sql_id is null)
            order by 1,4
)t1
```

I think you can find easy way, but i hope this resolve give you good direction.

Comment: No need to create 8 levels of aggregation using CUBE and then delete 6 of them, Simply define what you want using GROUPING SETS :-)